# Call a UIViewController with NavigationController programmatically in SWIFT 2.x

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to call a UIViewController with NavigationController designed in Storyboard programmatically when I select a dynamic shortcut.

I designed my UIViewController and its NavigationController in Main.storyboard and I put a storyboard ID (I called it MyUICtrlStoryID)

In order to create my dynamic shortcut I wrote the following code in the AppDelegate:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: Bool -> Void) {




        let handledShortCutItem = shortcutItem.type // handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem)

        if handledShortCutItem == "3DTouchShourtcutID"{

            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

//FirstViewcontroller UI will be called as root UIView
            let initialViewControlleripad : FirstViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewControllerID") as! FirstViewController



            initialViewControlleripad.go2MySecondUI = true   //set this check variable in order to launch my second UI View from the first one.

            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
      }
```

in the viewWillAppear function of my FistViewController

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {

                let shortcutItem = UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: "3DTouchShortcutID",
                    localizedTitle:    "This action",
                    localizedSubtitle: "action description",
                    icon: UIApplicationShortcutIcon(type: UIApplicationShortcutIconType.Add),
                    userInfo: nil)


                UIApplication.sharedApplication().shortcutItems = [shortcutItem]

                //check if FirstViewControler had to call the second UI 
                if go2MySecondUI == true {
                    self.go2MySecondUI = false


                            let newViewCtrl = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyUICtrlStoryID") as? SecondViewController
                           // call second UI view

                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                       self.presentViewController(newViewCtrl!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                   }
                                              //  }
                }
```

This code works fine: when I select, by 3d touch, my shortcut, my secondviewcontroller will be call and its UIView will be showed .. but without its navigation controller.
otherwise if I call my secondUIcontroller by a button designed in storyboard (with related segue callback) the secondUIView will be showed with navigation controller correctly..

What is wrong?

Comment: Why are you pushing the view controller then presenting the same view controller? self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewCtrl!, animated: true)
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                       self.presentViewController(newViewCtrl!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                   }

Comment: @beyowulf : Uh I'm sorry! I forget to remove it .. but, of course, it doen't resolve my problem :S

Comment: push don't present (i.e. delete dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.presentViewController(newViewCtrl!, animated: true, completion: nil) } and just say self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewCtrl!, animated: true)  make sure self.navigationController is not nil. Even better might be to just call self.preformSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: @beyowulf unfortunately if I use self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewCtrl!, animated: true)  it will not work . Moreover, in Swift 2.1, you have to use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())

Comment: You want to know why the view controller is not in a navigation controller. It is because you are presenting it modally. You need to say something like self.navigationController.pushViewController or self.navigationController.showViewController. This will only work if firstViewController is itself embedded in a navigationController. If fine to dispatch to the main queue but is only necessary if the method might be called from a different thread which viewWillAppear will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed your first view controller in a UINavigationController. So in the AppDelegate your code should be:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: Bool -> Void) {




        let handledShortCutItem = shortcutItem.type // handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem)

        if handledShortCutItem == "3DTouchShourtcutID"{

            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

//FirstViewcontroller UI will be called as root UIView
            let initialViewControlleripad : FirstViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewControllerID") as! FirstViewController



            initialViewControlleripad.go2MySecondUI = true   //set this check variable in order to launch my second UI View from the first one.
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewControlleripad)

            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
      }
```

Then in viewWillAppear of the FirstViewController you need to push the second view controller rather than present. So your code should read:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {

                let shortcutItem = UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: "3DTouchShortcutID",
                    localizedTitle:    "This action",
                    localizedSubtitle: "action description",
                    icon: UIApplicationShortcutIcon(type: UIApplicationShortcutIconType.Add),
                    userInfo: nil)


                UIApplication.sharedApplication().shortcutItems = [shortcutItem]

                //check if FirstViewControler had to call the second UI 
                if go2MySecondUI == true {
                    self.go2MySecondUI = false


                            let newViewCtrl = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyUICtrlStoryID") as? SecondViewController
                           // call second UI view

                           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewCtrl, animated: true)

                                              //  }
                }
```